# what is the small label marker element in material design called?

Tags: material-design, google-materials-design

I am new to material design and UI. In the below image what is the highlighted part in red called ?

[image]

Its called something but i don't know the exact name, Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be, it's what Material Design guidelines call "Chips", or something similar to that:

https://m3.material.io/components/chips/overview

Comment: its kind of, its not rectangle ...they are called something which i am not getting..

Comment: exp is right, they are called chips.
https://getmdl.io/components/#chips-section

You can check this link for some other variations.

Answer (score 0):

The description (text) itself is often referred to as a "tag".
However, the element name varies depending on what framework you use for design.

In bootstrap, these are called "badges": https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/